# ngIf before saving a div as a PDF doesn't seems to work in time

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to save up a huge div to a PDF file.
Right before doing the whole process of saving, I'm removing few balise of that div with *ngIf (and the boolean isExport)

Right when I clic on the function DownloadPage(), the balise I want to remove disappear but when the file is saved, they are still present.
how come ?

Should I call a delay method to give the DOM time to update ?

```
public downloadPage(): void {
  this.isExport = true;
  this.withoutFloorDetailsBlock = true;

  var data = document.getElementById('plan-cp');
  html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
    // Few necessary setting options  
    var imgWidth = 208;
    var pageHeight = 295;
    var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
    var heightLeft = imgHeight;

    const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
    let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
    var position = 0;
    pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    let now = new Date();
    let date = formatDate(now,"MMddyyyy",'en-EN');
    let name = this.asset.property_name + '_plan_' + date + '.pdf';
    pdf.save(name); // Generated PDF   
  });
}
```

Comment: Where is `this.isExport = false;` statement to hide that div?

Comment: @KaustubhKhare this.isExport = true is set to hide/delete some div in my template.
I didn't wrote the = false yet, because it's not even working without

Answer (score 1):

Like you said you will need to delay to give to angular the time to refresh the page (degist cycle), to do this using  setTimeout is in most case the solution

```
      this.isExport = true;

      setTimeout( () => {
        this.withoutFloorDetailsBlock = true;

        var data = document.getElementById('plan-cp');
        html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
          // Few necessary setting options  
          const imgWidth = 208;
          const pageHeight = 295;
          const imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
          const heightLeft = imgHeight;

          const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
          let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
          const position = 0;
          pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
          let now = new Date();
          let date = formatDate(now,"MMddyyyy",'en-EN');
          let name = this.asset.property_name + '_plan_' + date + '.pdf';
          pdf.save(name); // Generated PDF   
        });
      });
```